# How to transform key from json data case insensitive in python?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a json which has data that comes from multiple sources and a particular field key is inconsistent in terms of case. For example there is one column as data which has jsons inside it.

```
{"type": "Log", "country": "US", "ChangeId": 6} 
{"type": "Log", "country": "US", "ChangeID": 6}
```

Here above the ID in ChangeId is not consistent. Sometimes it is coming as Id.

I am able to parse this out and I am having no issues, but for learning purpose I want to know if it is possible to convert all the keys to lowercase in a json or do any manipulation like that with keys?

What I am doing right now is I am reading through the json which is coming from a database table separately and storing it in 2 dataframes (key/values as rows/columns) and joining them together (like a union). I would rather prefer to read all the json together, clean it in such a way that all ChangeId is converted to ChangeID or vice versa and then I can do the processing in a single dataframe.

Thanks.

Comment: can't you just convert all to lower case before parsing the text as json?

Comment: No, because I want to keep the values as is. That will convert all the values too. I thought of it. This is for representation purpose. In reality my json has over 50 key/value pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trying and looking through answers from an another stack overflow question, I got this working. See below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"data": [{"type": "Log", "country": "US", "ChangeId": 6}, {"type": "Log", "country": "US", "ChangeID": 6}]})
df["data"] = df["data"].apply(lambda x: {k.lower(): v for k,v in x.items()})

df
```